# css background-image stretching on transition with different image sizes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want my `background-image` with a smooth transition. When it has a different aspect-ratio predecessor. Here you'll see a example of this stretching effect.

```js
toggle = true

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".button").on("click", function() {
    if (toggle) {
      jQuery(".test").css("background-image", "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/4534200/pexels-photo-4534200.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-arthouse-studio-4534200.jpg&fm=jpg')")
      toggle = false
    } else {
      jQuery(".test").css("background-image", "url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547922374-968968e3f658?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=bosco-shots-SlR66yjPsoI-unsplash.jpg')")
      toggle = true
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547922374-968968e3f658?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=bosco-shots-SlR66yjPsoI-unsplash.jpg');
  transition: background-image 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
  -o-transition: background-image 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.button {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="change">
</div>
```

If anyone could show me an option, where I can still use `background-size: cover;`, and a `background-image` transition, it would help me a lot.

Comment: This is working fine in Chromium browsers, but not in Firefox. So I guess some browsers take image dimensions into account when doing transitions, and others don't. So there isn't really anything you could to about it, other than faking the whole thing with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of toggling the background image you can have multiple elements with a background and show the `active` element based on an index.

The [remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) for the (active) index makes sure we always have a valid index that never exceeds the amount of backgrounds we have.

```js
let active = 0; // First element is active

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    // Update active index
    active = (active + 1) % $(".bg").length;
    
    // Show active background
    $(".bg").each(function(index) {
      if(index === active) {
        $(this).addClass("bg-active");
      }else{
        $(this).removeClass("bg-active");
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.test > * {
  position: relative; /* Make sure elements inside `.test` dont disappear behind the background(s) */
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg-nature {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/4534200/pexels-photo-4534200.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-arthouse-studio-4534200.jpg&fm=jpg');
}

.bg-art {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547922374-968968e3f658?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&dl=bosco-shots-SlR66yjPsoI-unsplash.jpg');
}

.bg-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <div class="bg bg-nature bg-active"></div>
  <div class="bg bg-art"></div>

  <input class="button" type="button" value="change">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the transition with one div and without opacity? And I want the transition form image to image, not image to backgroudcolor(white) to image.